# Segmentation fault storing input in an array

Tags: c

I have written a C program that takes multiple inputs in the following format: rounds -> rows -> col -> array initial values

I have no issue with the following input: 2 2 2 0 0 0 0

but once put into the other format which looks like this

```
2
2 2
0 0
0 0
```

I get a segmentation fault, which I'm not sure why. I feel like I have newlines accounted for. Here is a snippet of my code where I think the error is happening:

```
int counter = 1;
char *num;
char *str;
long nums;
char line[BUFFER];
fgets (line, BUFFER, stdin);

num = strtok(line, " "); //getting first input that is separated by a space
int rounds = atoi(num); //changes input into a number
num = strtok(NULL, " ");
int row = atoi(num);
num = strtok(NULL, " ");
int col = atoi(num);
int grid[row][col];
for (int i = 0; i < row && !stop; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < col && !stop; j++){
        num = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        if (num == NULL){ //if the next character after whitespace is null/eof
            printf("Invalid input 1");
            stop = true;
        }else{
            nums = strtol(num, &str, 10);
            if (*str != '\0' && *str != '\n'){
                printf("Invalid input\n");
                return 1;
            }
            int curr = nums;
            grid[i][j] = curr;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I realize the problem here now, but how would I distinguish if the input is put in the format of a single line vs if the input were on multiple lines so I could use fgets?

Comment: If your input has several lines, you should read those lines with `fgets`. You only read one line and will pass `NULL` to `atoi`.

Comment: Sorry about the title issue; I posted the same question last night but I didn't include parts of code of how I got rows and columns

Comment: How would I get the program to read the input if it's all in a single line then if I'm using multiple fgets (don't they read a new line each time?)

Comment: Do you want to accept both formats? Or, more generally, do you care about the line breaks at all? You could read a new line when `strtok` returns `NULL` and you still want input. Of course, your `BUFFER` might not be big enough for serious input. Or you could use `scanf`, which doesn't care about new-lines.

Comment: Don't use either `strtok` or `atoi`.  This is a job either for `fgets` and `strtol` or just plan `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

If one doesn't care about whitespace, one could completely decouple the input from the parsing. In this modified code, `number` takes a `Buffer`, and calls `next_int`; if this fails, (it will the first time because the buffer is empty,) the line buffer is refilled by calling `next_line` until it gets at least one number. In this way, it's kind of a singleton producer-consumer pattern.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* EXIT malloc free strtol */
#include <stdio.h>  /* printf fgets perror */
#include <assert.h> /* assert */
#include <errno.h>  /* errno */
#include <string.h> /* strlen */
#include <limits.h> /* INT LONG */
#include <ctype.h>  /* isspace */

/** Returns true if `line` was filled up, at most to `size` from `stdin`, thus
 this limits the input we can get from `stdin` on top of `fgets`, (embedded
 NULs don't work.) If false, `errno` will be set. */
static int next_line(char *line, const size_t size) {
    assert(line && size > 2);
    if(!fgets(line, size, stdin)) {
        if(!ferror(stdin)) fprintf(stderr, "Not enough numbers.\n");
        if(!errno) errno = EDOM; /* This is an error in this application. */
        return 0;
    }
    if(line[0] == '\0' || line[strlen(line) - 1] != '\n')
        return errno = ERANGE, 0; /* Line too long. */
    return 1;
}

/** If EOF, line contained no non-whitespace characters, otherwise, if true,
 `*input_ptr` is a whitespace and then number in the range of
 `[MIN_INT, MAX_INT]`; it gets moved ahead that amount and `*output_ptr`
 contains the number. If false, `errno` will be set. */
static int next_int(char **const input_ptr, int *const output_ptr) {
    long l;
    assert(input_ptr && output_ptr);
    /* We could skip this, but then `errno` would possibly be set. */
    while(isspace(**input_ptr)) (*input_ptr)++;
    if(**input_ptr == '\0') return EOF;
    /* Perform the conversion to `int` using a `long`. */
    errno = 0;
    l = strtol(*input_ptr, input_ptr, 0);
    if((l == 0 || l == LONG_MAX || l == LONG_MIN) && errno) return 0;
    if(l > INT_MAX || l < INT_MIN) return errno = ERANGE, 0;
    *output_ptr = (int)l;
    return 1;
}

/* `sizeof str` is the maximum line. */
struct Buffer { char str[256], *line; };

/** A true return means that we filled the buffer `in` as needed to get an
 input `int` which is stored in `no`. Otherwise, `errno`. */
static int number(struct Buffer *const in, int *const no) {
    int success;
    assert(in && in->line >= in->str && in->line <= in->str + sizeof in->str);
    while((success = next_int(&in->line, no)) == EOF) {
        if(!next_line(in->str, sizeof in->str)) return 0;
        in->line = in->str;
    }
    return success;
}

int main(void) {
    int success = EXIT_FAILURE;
    int row, col, *array = 0, i, j;
    size_t n = 0, n_max;
    struct Buffer in = { "", 0 };
    in.line = in.str; /* Complete the `struct Buffer` contract. */
    if(!number(&in, &row) || !number(&in, &col)) goto catch;
    if(row <= 0 || col <= 0
        || (size_t)row > (size_t)-1 / col
        || (size_t)row * col > (size_t)-1 / sizeof *array)
        { errno = ERANGE; goto catch; } /* Overflow data types. */
    n_max = row * col;
    if(!(array = malloc(sizeof *array * n_max))) goto catch;
    for(n = 0; n < n_max; n++) if(!number(&in, array + n)) goto catch;
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            printf("%s%4d", i ? ", " : "", array[j * row + i]);
        }
        fputc('\n', stdout);
    }
    success = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    goto finally;
catch:
    perror("array");
finally:
    free(array);
    return success;
}
```

Also changed,

- [`strtol`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) is used instead of [`atoi`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html), which is equivalent, but it updates the pointer, has more error reporting, and can handle octal and hex.
- `C99` [varible-length arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) are going to cause stack overflow if one makes them too big. In `C17`, they are optional. The code above uses `malloc` instead.

Comment: I think this answer is basically re-implementing part of  `scanf` already implemented in the standard library...

Comment: @hyde Good point; one could write the consumer more succinctly as `next_int(...) { ... unsigned pos; ... if(sscanf(*input_ptr, " %d%n", &output, &pos) != 2) return 0; *input_ptr += pos; ... }`. However, it's difficult to tell when a number is out of `[INT_MIN, INT_MAX]` and I expect this to be slower, (much more general function.)